# two mode squeezed state in coherent state basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-optics, squeezed-states

It is known that, in the Fock basis, the two-mode squeezed state takes the form
$$
\vert TMSS \rangle = \sum_n \dfrac{(-e^{i\phi} \tanh(r))^n}{\cosh(r)} \vert n,n \rangle \;.
$$

An other possibility is to write such state in the coherent state basis, $\vert \alpha \rangle$. In this case, the result seems to be [Eq. 19 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0003077.pdf ]
$$
\vert TMSS \rangle = \dfrac{1}{\pi \sinh(r)} \int d^2\beta e^{-\frac{1-\tanh(r) \vert\beta\vert^2 }{\tanh(r)}} \vert \beta,\beta^\ast \rangle \;.
$$

I tried to derive the latter result from the former expression, but without success. My approach consisted of inserting the completeness relation $\frac{1}{\pi}\int d^2\alpha_i \vert\alpha_i\rangle\langle\alpha_i\vert = 1$. However, inserting one of such relation per each mode ($i=1,2$), I don't see where a condition that imposes $\alpha_1=\beta$, $\alpha_2=\beta^\ast$.

EDIT: my question consists of understanding the steps to obtain the representation of the TMSSS in the coherent-state basis, as written above.

Comment: The basis is overcomplete. It is unlikely that this is the only solution.  Also, it is not clear what your question is.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I edited my question, just asking for the derivation of the second expression.

Comment: What is not so clear to me is why you want to derive this from the first expression. Wouldn't it be easier to apply the squeezing operator to a two-mode vaccum?

Comment: This looks suspicious, if you substitute the expression for the coherent states the integral over beta gives a $\delta_{nm}$ (good), but it also diverges (bad).